# SQL query filter by modified date

Tags: sql, toad

I beg your pardon for my English in advance.

I have this data:

[image: DATA]

I need to get the max process for the `OP` column in a given `Start_date`.

That should look like this:

[image: Result]

I can't get that, any help would be appreciated

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1):

Toad is often used with Oracle, so I'll use Oracle syntax.  You can adapt for other databases.  The key is extracting the date from `start_date`.

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by trunc(start_date) order by start_date desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```